# How to use bitwise operators in an elixir when guard clause?

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I have the following function, that needs to match only with values of `n` being a power of 2 integers (`1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, ...`):

```
defmodule MyModule do
  def my_func(n) when is_power_of_two(n) do
     ## Some expression
  end
  def is_power_of_two(x) do
    (x != 0)
        and (x &&& (x - 1)) == 0)
  end
end
```

First, I tried defining `is_power_of_two` as a function in the module but it didn't work and I got this error:

`cannot invoke local is_power_of_two/1 inside guard`.

Following this [blog post](http://keathley.io/2016/04/09/elixir-guard-clauses.html), I tried to define it as the following macro:

```
defmodule MyModule.Util do
  defmacro is_power_of_two(x) do
    quote do
      (unquote(x) != 0)
        and ((unquote(x) &&& (unquote(x) - 1)) == 0)
    end
  end
end
```

Didn't work as well and I get the following error:

`cannot invoke local &&&/2 inside guard`

It seems that the bitwise `&&&` operator cannot be called from a `when` clause after the macro expansion.

**How to perform matches that requires guards containing bitwise operators?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is misleading. You're just missing an `import Bitwise` in `MyModule.Util`. The code works if I add the `import`:

```
defmodule MyModule.Util do
  import Bitwise

  defmacro is_power_of_two(x) do
    quote do
      (unquote(x) != 0) and ((unquote(x) &&& (unquote(x) - 1)) == 0)
    end
  end
end

defmodule MyModule do
  import MyModule.Util

  def my_func(n) when is_power_of_two(n) do
    true
  end
  def my_func(_), do: false
end

IO.inspect MyModule.my_func(128)
IO.inspect MyModule.my_func(129)
```

Output:

```
true
false
```